# Rails link_to tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My route is:

```
get "user" =>"user#info"
get "user/info"
```

It means that I set the `user/info` as the default action of controller `user`.When I visit the url`http://192.168.0.198:3000/user` It works.

Now,I want to create a link:

```
link_to 'Home',{:controller=>'user'}
```

But I got the error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"user"}
```

If I write :

```
link_to 'Home',{:action=>'info':controller=>'user'}
```

It surely works.

But I just not want to write the action.So how should I do?

I get this in `Rails API`

```
link_to "Profiles", controller: "profiles"
# => <a href="/profiles">Profiles</a>
```

Why I got  Error?

Comment: What do you have in your routes file regarding "Profiles". Do you have something like `resources :profiles`, or anything like that?

Comment: I don't have resources.just `get "user" =>"user#info"` and `get "user/info"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
link_to 'Home',user_info_path
```

Comment: This will work,thanks!But my issue is  why `link_to "Profiles", controller: "profiles"` rails error